# timing application with output redirection

Tags: shell, output

I am executing a program in shell and redirecting output:

```
nice -10 appname > /tmp/output.log 2>&1
```

I also need to time the execution. `time` command works, but the output from it also gets written to *output.log* altogether with the output from the main application:

```
time -p nice -10 appname > /tmp/output.log 2>&1
```

I tried enclosing the app in parentheses, but that throws an error:

```
time -p (nice -10 appname > /tmp/output.log 2>&1)
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

How can I write `time` output to stdout, while still redirecting application output to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dummy `printf`/`echo`:

```
time -p printf "$(nice -10 appname > /tmp/output.log 2>&1)"
```

---

Or here document:

```
time -p sh <<EOF
nice -10 appname > /tmp/output.log 2>&1
EOF
```

---

Or using the `-c` option of Shell:

```
time -p sh -c "nice -10 appname > /tmp/output.log 2>&1"
```

---

Or a function (Bash):

```
nicefun(){
nice -10 appname > /tmp/output.log 2>&1
}
time -p nicefun
```

---

Or a dedicated script:

**nice.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
nice -10 appname > /tmp/output.log 2>&1
```

Usage:

```
time -p path/to/nice.sh
```

Comment: bravo, quite a plethora of options! Good luck to all.

Comment: `printf` works but complains: `(time -p printf $(uptime > /tmp/foo) printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments])` - but `echo` works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Rytis quoting should solve it:  `time -p printf "$(uptime > /tmp/foo)"` It is because `printf` takes at least one argument where `echo` can work with no argument graciously. N.B:  `"$(uptime > /tmp/foo)"` is an empty string